# Adding data to CarouselView item source results in error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin CarouselView initialized with an empty `ObservableCollection`. The Carousel view correctly shows the `EmptyView` on page load.

However, when I add an item to the Observable Collection iOS throws the following exception:

`attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update`

The way I'm populating the item source is after the page loads I've hooked a button to an event handler to add items to the Observable Collection.

If I initialize the Observable Collection with initial data then the CarouselView works fine, it's just when I add items later that it breaks.

Page:

```
...
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:MatchesPageViewModel></viewModel:MatchesPageViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<CarouselView Margin="-10,15,-10,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PendingMatches}"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
              IsSwipeEnabled="True"
              VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <CarouselView.EmptyView>
        <Frame>
            <Label Text="It's empty"></Label>
        </Frame>
    </CarouselView.EmptyView>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="Some Content"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

View Model:

```
public class MatchesPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MatchResponse> PendingMatches { get; set; } =
        new ObservableCollection<MatchResponse>();

    //pretend it's invoked from a button in the page
    public void SomeEventHandler()
    {
        //throws exception: attempt to insert item 0 into section 0...
        PendingMatches.Add(new MatchResponse());
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code, but can not reproduce your error. You use button command to add item in observablecollection?Can your provide entire sample to test?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I noticed that This works perfectly if I define the ObservableCollection in the code behind, but if I declare it in the View Model it causes this error. I've tried a different page, stripping down the example etc and I can still reproduce it. I've also tried initiliaizing the ViewModel in codebehind as well.

Comment: Do you try to test my reply code? I use the following code , it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you may have some problem about adding item in observablecollection for Button click method. I do one demo using Button command binding that you can take a look.

```
  <CarouselView
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PendingMatches}"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.EmptyView>
                <Frame>
                    <Label Text="It's empty" />
                </Frame>
            </CarouselView.EmptyView>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding str}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Command="{Binding command1}"
            Text="add data" />

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{     
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new MatchesPageViewModel();
    }       
}

public class MatchesPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MatchResponse> PendingMatches { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MatchResponse>();
    public ICommand command1 { get; set; }
    public MatchesPageViewModel()
    {
        command1 = new Command(SomeEventHandler);
    }

    public void SomeEventHandler()
    {
        //throws exception: attempt to insert item 0 into section 0...
        PendingMatches.Add(new MatchResponse() { str = "test" });
    }
}
public class MatchResponse
{
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```